# Travel out of Australia with 3 Android tablets

Tags: australia, import-taxes

I am not an Australian citizen, but I am visiting Brisbane and plan to fly back to my country with 3 Android Tablets for three of my children. Total cost of items approximately $300

Will I be required to pay a duty tax on these items at the point of departure - Brisbane International Airport?

Or will I have to pay duty tax upon arrival in my home country?

I would appreciate feedback from travellers who've had to negotiate similar experiences.

Comment: You won't pay duty on an export. Whether you have to pay duty in your home country depends on the regulations there. Which is your home country?

Comment: You might even be able to get the sales tax back from Australia, if you get the right paperwork.

Answer (score 2):

There is no export duty. The Australian government will be happy you're spending your money in Australia, and as mentioned, you can even get the VAT tax back, if you care to learn the process and fill the right forms.

Duties are due when *entering* a country, not when leaving. When you arrive at your destination (where the bought tablets will *stay*), you might have to pay customs duty; this depends of course on your country (which you didn't specify).

Typical European countries and the US have limits around 400 - 1000 $, but your country might be different.

Comment: "...you can even get the VAT tax back..." just to improve your chances the tax which you might be able to get refunded is referred to as "GST" in Australia. It is indeed a value added tax but it's not generally referred to as "VAT". There's some text here about the process of getting a refund : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goods_and_services_tax_(Australia)#Tourist_refund_scheme

Comment: @glaucon The government site might be a more complete reference: https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/tourist-refund-scheme/for-travellers